# Fpdf in function

Tags: fpdf

I need to call fpdf function by ajax.
User fill the form and pdf file is formed.

When I write a function

```
 if(!function_exists('ajax_add_pdf_file')) {
    function ajax_add_pdf_file(){


        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf -> AddPage();

$pdf -> SetFont('Arial', 'B', 18);

$pdf -> Cell(40,10,'Hello '.$firstname.' '.$lastname);
$pdf -> Cell(40,10,'Email: '.$email);


$savefolder = realpath('../../../applications');

$filename = $firstname.'12.pdf';

$savefile = $savefolder.'/'.$filename;

$pdf->Output(F, $savefile);


    }
}
```

Nothing happened.
When I just save file without function - it's ok. PDF-file is saved

Help, please.

Answer (score 1):

This link (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generating-pdfs-with-php--pre-10944) shows how to create a form that a user will fill out and then subsequently create a pdf file from the form data. Not only does the author have a video walkthrough of how to do it, he also provides detailed explanations of each code section.

The section that you might want to take note of in that link is where the author pulls the form data and directly assigns them to the cells.

```
$pdf->SetX(140); 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'I'); 
$pdf->Cell(200, 15, $_POST['address'], 0, 2); 
$pdf->Cell(200, 15, $_POST['city'] . ', ' . $_POST['province'], 0, 2); 
$pdf->Cell(200, 15, $_POST['postal_code'] . ' ' . $_POST['country']); 
$pdf->Ln(100);
```

I'm not quite sure why you would want to check if your ajax_add_pdf_file doesn't exist. It seems unnecessary to me.